# Set Git Tag to testing Branch

Tags: git, tags

I'm currently getting started with tagging in git.

Right now I'm having a `master` branch for production ready and tested code and a `develop` branch.
When fixing bugs or implementing new issues I'm always creating new branches based on `develop`.
When I feel there is enough work done for a new release I merge `develop` into `master` and tag it with a version Number.

The thing is I also use this tag in my UI as a version number. 
For example: `v0.3.1-NumbersOfCommitsAheadOfTag-CommitSignature`.

Since I'm always creating my tags on `master` I'm always on the same version on my `develop` branch since it got created.

What can I do here? Do I need to merge `master` back into `develop`?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

If master does not contains commits, a merge should not be done and this because develop already contains all the master's commits. If you use master only for tags I think you have to leave master branch and never merge back it to develop branch.